# Why not change Luke’s last name?

Tags: star-wars

After *Revenge of the Sith* when Luke and Leia are born, they are hidden so that Darth Vader, their father, won’t find them. But, they changed Leia's last name because she was adopted by Senator Organa and his wife so they changed hers to Leia Organa. I know that Luke was adopted by his aunt and uncle but still, why wouldn’t they change his last name? Skywalker wasn’t a very common name then so if Vader ever heard of a Skywalker living on Tatooine, he would most likely suspect something.

So why not change Luke’s last name so that all of any suspicion could be avoided?

Comment: Just a question, are we sure that Skywalker isn't a common name? We never see another one having this name, it's true, but are we sure it's not a common name on Tatooine?

Comment: Skywalker was Annakin's name -- presumably his mother had relatives, perhaps even on Tatooine.  "Oh, another cousin."

Comment: They thought about renaming him Luke [Starkiller](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars:_From_The_Adventures_of_Luke_Starkiller), but it sounded so dumb they decided they'd rather risk being hunted down by Darth Vader.